# Very high loss value despite a very good accuracy

Tags: python, performance, deep-learning, neural-network, loss

i am trying to solve my problem but i could not go one step further. here is the shape of datasets :

```
Distribution of training and test data
--------------------------------------
Training_input dataset (x_train): (824, 2775)
*******
Test_input dataset (x_test): (406, 2775)
*******
Train_output dataset (y_train): (824, 75)
*******
Test_output dataset (y_test): (406, 75)
*******
```

and here is my NN model :

```
from tensorflow.keras import losses
#Erzeugen eines neuronalen Netzes:
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='sigmoid',input_dim=2775))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300, activation='linear'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(250, activation='linear'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(train_outputData.shape[-1], activation='sigmoid'))

#Optimizationsmethode des Gradient Descent  
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])

#Durchführung des Trainings:

batch_size=32
model.fit(train_inputData, train_outputData,epochs=50, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(test_inputData,test_outputData),verbose=2)
```

please see my output: (see the figure)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4lHd.png)

i dont know why i get such an extreme high loss value. How can i fix it?

Comment: What is the range of values in Train_output dataset?

Comment: (824,50). I had normalized input array and labels. Now I am able to reduce the loss value. But now, i have an accuracy around 5%

Comment: Your model has a sigmoid activation at the output layer. This means that the output is in [0.0-1.0] range. You have to make sure that Train_output is also in this range.